# Complex differentiation of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $ f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} $ is $ \mathbb{C} $ differentiable. Denote its derivative as $ f'(z) $.

Next, if we denote $ f(z)=u(z)+iv(z) $ where $u,v $ are functions to $ \mathbb{R} $, then the partial derivatives of $$ f\left(x,y\right)=\begin{pmatrix}u\left(x,y\right)\\
v\left(x,y\right)
\end{pmatrix} $$

Satisfies:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(z\right)=-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(z\right)=f'\left(z\right) $$

Why is this true?

I couldnt find formal proof for this equation, just intuitive explanations (that werent very convincing).

I'll be glad to see a formal proof for this equation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h$, then, in particular,$$f'(z)=\lim_{h\to0,\,h\in\Bbb R}\frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z).$$On the other hand, if $z=a+bi$, then$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(a,b)+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(a,b)i.\tag1$$But you can use here the Cauchy-Riemann equations $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. So, $(1)$ tells you that\begin{align}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(z)&=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(a,b)-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(a,b)i\\&=-\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(a,b)+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(a,b)i\right)i\\&=-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z).\end{align}

---

If you want to use this to *deduce* the Cauchy-Riemann equations, then note that you also have\begin{align}f'(z)&=\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\Bbb R}\frac{f(z+hi)-f(z)}{hi}\\&=-i\lim_{h\to0,\ h\in\Bbb R}\frac{f(z+hi)-f(z)}h\\&=-i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z).\end{align}

Comment: Actually my lecturer used this fact in order to prove Cauchy-Riemann, so using CR to prove this equation would be circular reasoning. The explanation to this equation that was given was rather intuitive than a formal proof.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Why  $ \lim_{\underset{h\in\mathbb{C}}{h\to0}}\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h}=\lim_{\underset{h\in\mathbb{R}}{h\to0}}\frac{f\left(z+h\right)-f\left(z\right)}{h} $ ? My lecturer says that since in $ \mathbb{R} $ in order for a limit to exist, both one sided limits should be equal, so in the same way here those limits should be equal. But this seems to me like just an intuitive explanation and not a formal proof

Comment: Also if we think about a complex function $ f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2} $, then the partial derivative does not equal to the differential at all, so it confuses me why in this case we do agree that they equal

Comment: I disagree. Do you want a formal proof? Here it is. Assume that $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=l$. I will proof that $\lim_{z\to0,\,z\in\Bbb R}f(z)=l$ too. Just consider the map $\varphi\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ defined by $\varphi(x)=x$. Since $\varphi$ is continuous and since $\lim_{x\to0}\varphi(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to0}f\bigl(\varphi(x)\bigr)=\lim_{z\to0}f(z)=l$. In other words, $\lim_{z\to0,\,z\in\Bbb R}f(z)=l$.

Comment: Concerning your other question, I do not know what the differential is, and therefore I have nothing to say.

Comment: Anyway, if you did not like my answer, then say so and I will delete it.

Comment: @Your answer is very helpful. Thanks !